# R: tokenize n-grams but not strip punctuations

Tags: r, token, n-gram, quanteda

I am trying to conduct tokenization of n-grams (between 1 (minimum) and 3(maximum)) on my data. After applying this function , I can see that it strips some relevant words such as [sad](words that I have converted from emojis).

For example the input is:

- I dislike lemons [sad]

When I apply the n-gram tokenizer and assess their frequency (which are separated by "_") the output for sad appears like this (bare in mind that I am only printing the top 100 n-grams and other words are included but I want to assess this one specifically):

- [_sad]
- [_sad _]

How do I make sure that "[" its not stripped during tokenization of n-grams? (i.e. In order to become [sad])

This is my code and I am using quanteda package:

```
tokens= tokens_ngrams(tokens(textcleaning), n=1:3)
```

Then I create a corpus object and built top 100 n-grams through term document matrix.

Comment: In the future you should probably specify which packages you are using and provide a minimal reproducible example of your problem. Your explanation is fairly clear, but it does not contain enough information for someone to answer it without either prior knowledge of {quanteda} or some help from you (e.g. the relevant library calls, and a sample text dataset that reproduces your problem)

Comment: @AndrewBrown thank you I have added further information - It is pretty hard to provide example as I am assessing the top 100 n-grams , and just trying to solve just that particular problem.

Comment: What if the tokens themselves contain a `_` ?

Comment: @wildplasser they don't as I have conducted text cleaning ( removal of all punctuations except "[" and "]" . The "_" is the output to separate words. For instance, the sentence "i am", if its an important feature will be outputted as "i_am" (bigram)

Comment: IMHO R is barely usable for low level tasks like this. The tokenisation should be done in a package. BTW: what would you do with `1!11!11`, or `...` ? Should these be a single token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played around with this a little bit -- and I am thinking you should convert your `[` and `]` characters to something unique but alphanumeric. It seems like {quanteda} wants to parse tokens that contain or are adjacent to special characters in this way -- and not consider them part of the "word" per se. Since your concept of "`[sad]`" is a single word, then to tokenize it, just do something that distinguishes it from regular `"sad"`.

I use `gsub` and search for patterns `"\\["` and `"\\]"` respectively. `[` is a regular expression special character so you need to escape it with *two* backslashes. I replace the first with the word `"emoji"` and the second with `""` to form `"emojisad"`

Note how the period at the end of the sentence is handled. You said you stripped out punctuation, but this behavior seems like a "feature" not a bug.

```r
library(quanteda, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
#> Package version: 2.1.2
#> Parallel computing: 2 of 8 threads used.
#> See https://quanteda.io for tutorials and examples.
#> 

test_string <- "I dislike lemons [sad]."

tokens_ngrams(tokens(gsub("\\[", "emoji", gsub("\\]", "", test_string))))
#> Tokens consisting of 1 document.
#> text1 :
#> [1] "I_dislike"       "dislike_lemons"  "lemons_emojisad" "emojisad_."
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: you are absolutely right- fabulous idea! thank you!!!!